# Вытащить данные из json

Tags: json, php, json_encode

Друзья, прошу помочь.

В многочисленных попытках вывести данные из этого файла запутался окончательно. =(

http://radio.globaltranceinvasion.com:8000/status-json.xsl - тут данные

Нужно вывести, к примеру, количество слушателей канала с `/iua_gtiradio`.

Вопрос: как это сделать? Помогите с решением.

Пробовал так:

```
$s = file_get_contents("http://radio.globaltranceinvasion.com:8000/status-json.xsl");
$access_staff = json_encode($s);

    $result = json_decode($access_staff); // отправка закпроса в u-crm

    echo 'Success: ' . $result['/radiohi']; // выводит статус добавления
```

Comment: в ответе с этой ссылки в хэдере text/html, а структура данных ответа - xml, поэтому json_decode() ни хрена понять не может, что это ей принесли...

Comment: Что делать? Проблема в том, что файл формируется icecast'ом, и я не могу его другого формата сделать, а как перекодировать, чтобы все заработало, не понимаю...

Comment: @deivan там не xml, там почти валидный json. На заголовки внутренней функции, конечно, плевать.

upd: хм, все-таки полуxml, был неправ

Comment: вот я о том же, там не все так просто. =/ Думал, хоп - сейчас вытащу json, будет работать, а тут на тебе - не работает. =( Что делать теперь, не пойму.

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, там *malformed* xml. Выполните `strip_tags()`, замените HTML-сущности на реальные символы, оберните в квадратные скобки (`[ + data + ]`) и распарсьте json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$s = file_get_contents("http://radio.globaltranceinvasion.com:8000/status-json.xsl");

if(null != preg_match('/radiohi&quot; : &quot;(\d+)&quot;}/i',$s,$m)) echo "Success: {$m[1]}";
```

Comment: не работает

Comment: поправил, теперь работает!